# I need help using ProxySelector to detect Proxy settings

Tags: java, http, proxy

I have created a Java Swing application. Some users can't connect to the internet when activating the application, checking program updates, etc. because they are using a Proxy.

I have been reading about the interesting [ProxySelector Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/proxies.html). It is very nice, but i have some questions about it please :

1. Will this class detect all types of Proxies that can be used(HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, SOCK,...) ?
2. If the Proxy used needs authentication, will this class get its information automatically ?
3. I have written code to get the Proxy settings used. Now i need to test this but i do not have a proxy, so i was going to set a proxy like the instructions [here](http://www.linquist.net/geek/proxy), but is there a faster method ? Can i use Public Proxies to test this like [hidemyass.com](http://hidemyass.com) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer all your questions, but here some of them:

1.I belive that it will use the proxy selector for HTTP, HTTPS ans SOCKS. AFAIK, FTP is not natively supported by the JVM.

2.For Authentication, you can use the following code:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    private URL previous;
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           try {
               if (previous == getRequestingURL())
                   count++;
               if (previous != getRequestingURL()) {
                   count = 0;
               } else {
                    if (count<3) {
                         // Ask for login/passwd to the user
                    } else {
                        // Throw a RuntimeException to prevent locking the account
                        throw new TooManyFailedAttemptException();
                    }

                   return new PasswordAuthentication("login", "password".toCharArray());
               }
          } finally {
               previous = getRequestingURL();
          }
    }
});
```

3.I guess that any public proxy is ok. I am not really sure on how you are going to ensure that your code is actually using it. Personally I set up a Squid proxy which is not that hard and there you can really trace your calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I was looking for a way to use Public Proxies inside my Java code, but i guess there is no way to do so.

Comment: I found that if i set a public Proxy data in Internet Explorer then it will be set in the System. And it has been detected fine by the Java code. But i am still unable to find Public Proxies with authentication data to test it on my code. Any help would be appreciated for this.